# Shifting cropped region of background images on smaller screen

Tags: css, image, background, media-queries, crop

Is there a way to change which part of a background image is cropped when the screen shrinks? I would like the far-left of the image to be the background on screen sizes:(max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px),      (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px).

On a full-size screen the text doesn't overlap with her face (she's a little off-center) but when the screen size is smaller it crops (to the center of the image) to show her face as the background and therefore the text goes over her face. url: http://tinyurl.com/onf333b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Just replace the

```
#wwm { 
background:url(../images/photos/meghasmiling.jpg) no-repeat center -1px fixed
}
```

with

```
#wwm { 
background:url(../images/photos/meghasmiling.jpg) no-repeat left -1px fixed
}
```